# How to setup IDP from scratch using opensso library?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam, opensso

I am aware that Forgerock owns OpenAM which can be used to setup IDP/SP. However, we have had our system set up as an SP using opensso library. This was done quite a few years back and all of the development is in java. I am trying to find resources/references to use the same library to setup our system as an IDP too. OpenAM requires us to deploy a war for initiating the configuration. However, that is not what I am looking for.
Can someone please direct me to the right resources/examples for setting up IDP using opensso? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The federation library of OpenAM was only meant to be consumed to fulfill the service provider role (this is what the OpenAM fedlet actually does).

There is no guarantee whatsoever that a standalone IdP can be implemented using the federation library without having a full OpenAM WAR file deployed.